# Where can I view all AWS S3 PUT requests?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I have setup an AWS S3 bucket for personal use and have configured a Lambda function running a Python script which runs at 12AM EST every day.

The Python script connects to the S3 bucket using boto3, downloads 3 files, modifies them and uploads them again.

By my reasoning this should mean that every day I should generate 3 S3 PUT requests on my AWS account. However, we are on the 4th day of the month and I have already racked up 58000 PUT requests.

Obviously I want this to stop however I'm not sure whether this is my Python script causing this or not.

Is there a way that I can view all S3 PUT requests on AWS with as much detail as possible?

Comment: You could consider activating CloudTrail. It won't give you access logs, but it does record all API Requests in the account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just follow the official documentation to enable S3 logging: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/server-access-logging.html

After enabling this option you'll be receiving log files that look like this:

```
79a59df900b949e55d96a1e698fbacedfd6e09d98eacf8f8d5218e7cd47ef2be mybucket [06/Feb/2014:00:00:38 +0000] 192.0.2.3 79a59df900b949e55d96a1e698fbacedfd6e09d98eacf8f8d5218e7cd47ef2be 3E57427F3EXAMPLE REST.GET.VERSIONING - "GET /mybucket?versioning HTTP/1.1" 200 - 113 - 7 - "-" "S3Console/0.4" -
79a59df900b949e55d96a1e698fbacedfd6e09d98eacf8f8d5218e7cd47ef2be mybucket [06/Feb/2014:00:00:38 +0000] 192.0.2.3 79a59df900b949e55d96a1e698fbacedfd6e09d98eacf8f8d5218e7cd47ef2be 891CE47D2EXAMPLE REST.GET.LOGGING_STATUS - "GET /mybucket?logging HTTP/1.1" 200 - 242 - 11 - "-" "S3Console/0.4" -
79a59df900b949e55d96a1e698fbacedfd6e09d98eacf8f8d5218e7cd47ef2be mybucket [06/Feb/2014:00:00:38 +0000] 192.0.2.3 79a59df900b949e55d96a1e698fbacedfd6e09d98eacf8f8d5218e7cd47ef2be A1206F460EXAMPLE REST.GET.BUCKETPOLICY - "GET /mybucket?policy HTTP/1.1" 404 NoSuchBucketPolicy 297 - 38 - "-" "S3Console/0.4" -
79a59df900b949e55d96a1e698fbacedfd6e09d98eacf8f8d5218e7cd47ef2be mybucket [06/Feb/2014:00:01:00 +0000] 192.0.2.3 79a59df900b949e55d96a1e698fbacedfd6e09d98eacf8f8d5218e7cd47ef2be 7B4A0FABBEXAMPLE REST.GET.VERSIONING - "GET /mybucket?versioning HTTP/1.1" 200 - 113 - 33 - "-" "S3Console/0.4" -
79a59df900b949e55d96a1e698fbacedfd6e09d98eacf8f8d5218e7cd47ef2be mybucket [06/Feb/2014:00:01:57 +0000] 192.0.2.3 79a59df900b949e55d96a1e698fbacedfd6e09d98eacf8f8d5218e7cd47ef2be DD6CC733AEXAMPLE REST.PUT.OBJECT s3-dg.pdf "PUT /mybucket/s3-dg.pdf HTTP/1.1" 200 - - 4406583 41754 28 "-" "S3Console/0.4" -
79a59df900b949e55d96a1e698fbacedfd6e09d98eacf8f8d5218e7cd47ef2be mybucket [06/Feb/2014:00:03:21 +0000] 192.0.2.3 79a59df900b949e55d96a1e698fbacedfd6e09d98eacf8f8d5218e7cd47ef2be BC3C074D0EXAMPLE REST.GET.VERSIONING - "GET /mybucket?versioning HTTP/1.1" 200 - 113 - 28 - "-" "S3Console/0.4" -
```

This should give you an idea of who does what with your bucket. You might have to wait for some time (several hours) for those logs to get delivered.

Comment: Can you also tell where to see logs themselves? I've enabled logging but I still don't know where to look after. Thanks.

Comment: @mimic When you enable logging, you specify a target bucket. The logs will be written to this bucket.

Comment: Sergy, thanks I see now! But it's awful, they created hundred files with a small piece of information in eash. And when I looked at them it has nothing to do with my site. It says about some problem with cors on JDK what is not about *my* website because it's written in Python. I'm really puzzled...